# API Platform: normalization context ignored in nested objects

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I have an API resource entity like this:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={},
 *     itemOperations={"get"},
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}},
 * )
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @var array<B>
     * @Groups("read")
     */
    private array $b;

    // ...
}
```

The `@Groups` annotation for properties works, I only get those with `@Groups("read")`.

But I have nested objects like this:

```
class B
{
    /**
     * @var array<C>
     * @Groups("read")
     */
    private array $c;

    // ...
}

class C
{

    /**
     * @Groups("read")
     */
    private string $foo;

    private string $bar;

    // ...
}
```

In `B`, the `@Groups` annotation is still respected, but in `C` I get all properties, completely ignoring annotations.

**Expected output like:**

```json
{
  "b": [
    {
      "c": [
        {
          "foo": "This should be public"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Got output like:**

```json
{
  "b": [
    {
      "c": [
        {
          "foo": "This should be public"
          "bar": "This should be private"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

*(if it matters, neither `B` nor `C` is an `@ApiResource`, but `C` is a Doctrine `@Entity`. I use a custom data provider for `A`)*

Answer (score 0):

I found it... `C` implemented `JsonSerializable`, for other reasons, and the JSON represenation from `jsonSerialize()` contained `foo` and `bar`.

API Platform apparently makes use of that if it exists. Something learned!